# how to change the hyperlink's color with a .selected with a ID name in it?

Tags: css, css-selectors

The code is like this

```
   <div class="header">
    <ul>
      <li>
         <a class="abc" id="abc">testing</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
```

I tried to use

```
    .header ul li.selected a
```

to change the link color but failed. It seems like it doesn't call the css since there is an ID and a class in the a tag.
I tried to use

```
    .header ul li.selected a .abc
```

but also failed.
So how can change the link name without removing class and id in the a tag since I have to keep class and id...

Thank you for helping!

Comment: Is "selected" a class name? Doesn't `<a class="abc selected" id="abc">` help?

Comment: Oh, actually is li.selected not a.selected.

Comment: need to see an example in order to debug...

Answer (score 1):

you havn't any class named `selected`. I think you want something like this

```
.header ul li a.abc
{
    color:yellow;
}
```

or you may be just want to change the color of anchor when it is clicked than you can use `:active` pseudo class

```
.header ul li a:active
{
    color:yellow;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/EHSVW/)